# Can not add items to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I can not add book in to MongoDB. I fill all the fields in my Web app and push button create but i got error message. This is my code:

```
// Create Book route
router.post('/', upload.single('cover'), async (req, res) => {
    const fileName = req.file != null ? req.file.filename : null;
    const book = new Book({
        title: req.body.title,
        author: req.body.author,
        publishDate: new Date(req.body.publishDate),    
        pageCount: req.body.pageCount,
        coverImageName: fileName,
        description: req.body.description
    });
    try {
        const newBook = await book.save();
        //res.redirect(`books/${newBook.id}`);
        res.redirect(`books`);
    } catch {
        if (book.coverImageName != null) {
            removeBookCover(book.coverImageName);
        }
        renderNewPage(res, book, true);
    }
});

async function renderNewPage(res, book, hasError = false) {
    try {
        const authors = await Author.find({});
        const params = {
            authors: authors,
            book: book
        }
        if (hasError) params.errorMessage = 'Error Creating Book'
        res.render('books/new', params);
    } catch {
        res.redirect('/books')
    }
}
```

My Schema: Book and Author is correct.

Comment: So you want to tell us what the error message is? While you're at it, can you explain what this middleware is doing? `upload.single('cover')`

Comment: I'm gonna upload a cover image of book so I use multer and var upload

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: ``` if (hasError) params.errorMessage = 'Error Creating Book' ```. Thats error message